# How can I inspect a huge mess of projects for references

Tags: architecture

My current workplace has several disconnected teams that depend on each other.
There are several legacy prjects with project files.

I want to find a way to find a way to visualize our architecture so we can identify "upward" references and nail down where we need to add additional testing.

Is there an automated or semi automated way to do that? The codebase is a mixed java / C# / c++ / ansi-c codebase.

Comment: I've never used it, but NDepend has an interesting afferent/efferent coupling analysis. The analysis is at the assembly level, and you have not specified at what level you want to test at so I am not sure that it is the right tool. I have also never seen it used with Java.

Comment: What is the total volume of code? What kind of code is it? What resources are available?

Comment: @Jonny in a sense testing is spread thin. So the answer to what testing will be applied I would start from Unit tests and work my way up to bigger clusters from there.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The Volumen Is years of company output stored in subversion. Some of it GUI, some of it Network, some of it Database. I can download all Sourcefiles and I have VMs where I can offload some workload.

Comment: But that tells nothing about the source code size (i.e. it would be different in a small entreprise with two separate teams of a few developers working for 5 years, and at Google or IBM which have over a billion lines of code, and certainly large teams providing inhouse tools)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Each Project is somewhere from 40k lines to 60k lines and there are about 130 Projects as far as I can tell. So... huge legacy.

Comment: I won't say *huge* (if you compare to the Linux kernel, or GCC, or Firefox which are all above ten millions lines) but *large* enough. You need several months of work (so you need to be sure to get the time and other resources for that).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for the warning. I will write up an internal proposal first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find a way to find a way to visualize our architecture so we can identify "upward" references

The point is that using any kind of tool requires some investment (at the very least, your time to master that tool, which means probably weeks of effort).
And that is worthwhile only for quite "large" software base (so if the total source code volume is only a few hundred thousands of source lines, it might not worth the effort, beyond what you already know and use).

> Is there an automated or semi automated way to do that? The codebase is a mixed java / C# / c++ / ansi-c codebase

Assuming the effort is worthwhile (and I am not sure of that) you might consider several existing static source code analyzers, or configure or build your own one above existing bases (like grep, [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), ctags, [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) -a domain specific language to customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler-, [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) -static C code analyzers framework-, [Rascal](http://www.rascal-mpl.org/), etc...)

The point is that choosing & learning any tool is likely to require at least a month of your work. Only you can know if it is worth trying (certainly yes if the total code base is above a million lines, and probably not if it is below a hundred thousands line).

Very probably (notably if you have software mixing several programming languages, e.g. some C++ code called from C# code) you'll need to tailor, combine, or customize several existing tools for your own needs. This raises the effort required to several months.

BTW, you might consider running something at version control commit time. If you are using [git](http://git-scm.com/), consider having some [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

<sup>NB: all the products mentioned above are free software or open source</sup>

<sup>P.S.: if you intend to use (or try) [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) be sure to contact me, since it is my work.</sup>